# Projection on Banach spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $P: X\rightarrow X$ with $P^2=P$, linear. Prove that $P$ is bounded $\iff X=\ker P \bigoplus PX$.

*Context*: exercise $5.14$ in Bollobas' Linear Analysis.

*My try*: since $P^2=P$, then $\exists x$ with $ Px=y \iff Py=y$, so $PX$ are the fixed points of $P$. Also, suppose $x \in PX\cap\ker P$. Then $x=Px=0$, therefore $PX\cap\ker P=\{0\}$.

Now, let $x \in X$. Then $P(x-Px)=Px-Px=0$, so that $PX+\ker P=X\implies X=\ker P \bigoplus PX$.

However I didn't use that $X$ is Banach, and neither I had to suppose that $X$ is continuous. In fact, I didn't use at all the topological structure of $X$. What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: $\oplus$ may mean topological sum, not algebraic sum.

Comment: So equality here is isometric isomorphism? (or linear homeorphism?)

Comment: Topological sum means that the projections on each element of the sum are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the projection $P$, the projection $p$ on $PX$ is equal to $P$. Therefore $p$ is continuous if and only if $P$ is bounded. As the projection $q$ on $\ker P$ is equal to $Id -p$, $q$ is also continuous if and only if $P$ is bounded as the identity is bounded.

Therefore $P$ bounded is equivalent to $X = \ker P \oplus PX$ where $\oplus$ stands for the topological sum.